# Trying to display current time HH:mm:ss.ff inside label

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to display current datetime inside a label displaying the counting milliseconds,seconds,minutes and hour. I did this, but it shows with some delay.

forgive me if I missing something obvious

```
Thread thUpdateTime = new Thread(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            txtTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ff");
        }));
    }
});
thUpdateTime.Name = "some description";
thUpdateTime.Start();
```

Comment: Maybe because you have a `  Thread.Sleep(100)`

Comment: but If I change it to 1 it gets really slow

Comment: "with some delay" How much delay?  More then 1/10 of a second?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it shows with some delay"?

Comment: no, if I change to Sleep(1) the count gets perfect but the UI gets a little slow, example: having a hardtime to minimize, drag window from one position to another

Comment: If you sleep by 1 ms the display will have to be updated one thousand times per second! Of course it will be slow. No one can read the time that fast anyway.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: Don't bother with milliseconds, people can barely see 10'ths (just watch a stop watch). That being said, I don't understand your question. It gets slow on 1ms delay (not surprising) and its not accurate to the millisecond on 100ms delay (obviously). What is your question?

Comment: As an aside, you may gain some performance by putting the while loop  inside the "Invoke" on the 1ms delay.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Wouldn't that freeze the UI? Maybe it helps to move the Sleep command to before the `Invoke` instead of inside.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, The sleep would prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a DispatcherTimer:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += (s, e) => txtTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
timer.Start();
```